# C# Modbus RS-485 tcp

Tags: c#, modbus

Всем привет, получается у меня есть роутер, на нем я открыл порт 11004 и сделал проброс порта на свой пк , так как я внутри сети роутера и сделал в роутере себе статический ip, есть терминал WRX-708 по интерфейсу RS-485, терминал я перепрошил на свой ip и порт сервера, регистрация в сети проходит, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но не могу понять как мне теперь из мой программы на C# сделать запрос на чтение регистров, попытался так , но пишет что Socket не открыт

```
       string ipAddress = "188.235.248.186";
        int tcpPort = 11004;
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(); //Create a new TcpClient object.
        tcpClient.BeginConnect(ipAddress, tcpPort, null, null);
        ModbusIpMaster master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(tcpClient);

        //  byte slaveID = _slaveId;
        ushort startAddress = 0;
        //84
        ushort numOfPoints = 84;

       ushort[] _holding_registerAsync = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(2, startAddress, numOfPoints);
```

Comment: tcpClient.BeginConnect -> tcpClient.Connect, не успевает подключиться походу.

Comment: @Blackmeser переделал на Connect, тогда вот такая ошибка, System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException: "Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение."

Comment: Смотрите лог роутера, пропускает ли он подключение, попробуйте указать другой конечный порт за NAT например на какой-нибудь web-сервер (они сейчас встроены почти в каждое приложение, нужно только включить) Попробуйте подключиться через терминал, а не своей программой.

Comment: @Blackmeser порт закрыт на серере почему-то, через 2ip попробовал, хотя правила в брандмаурере создал

Comment: Тут уже вопрос не программирования, а системного администрирования. Проверяйте свой код в локальной сети.

Comment: Вы на ответ в прошлом вопросе никак не отреагировали. Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа. Либо написать комментарий, почему ответ не был полезен,, возможно автор ответа сможет его исппавить или дополнить.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 0):

Сразу бросилось в глаза: статический IP комп имеет после роутера (в домашней/рабочей подсети). Его видят устройства только внутри этой подсети. Ваш терминал WRX-708 находится вне этой подсети - там же у вас сим-карта, а для мирового интернета придуманного вами в роутере IP адреса не существует. На упомянутом в комментариях 2ip можно увидеть свой "внешний" IP - вот он должен быть также статическим. Делает его статическим ваш провайдер (за доп.плату). Имея статический внешний IP, в вашем роутере нужно "привязать" открываемый порт к вашему ПК (видимо, через уже созданный вами внутренний статический IP). Тогда 2ip покажет открытый порт и терминал сможет стучаться в него, если он в режиме "клиента" (мастера. Мы ж ещё о модбасе говорим...).

Но приведённый код в вопросе говорит, что терминал работает в режиме сервера (slave). ПК - клиент. Чтобы клиент нашёл терминал, терминалу нужен статический IP. Зачем клиенту статический IP - тут я не в курсе (может для ПО терминала, может для безопасности и создания VPN это нужно?), но могу сказать, что в код c# вы пишете не ip:port ПК, а  статический ip:port терминала.

И вот тут момент такой, что ещё перед настройками ip/портов нужно определиться, кто сервер, а кто клиент (ваше устройство RS485 отправляет данные или же только отвечает).